Two Git Generators Using pathParamPrefix not working
Below is the sample code, in which I am trying to use two git generators. One will fetch information related to the application and the child generator will get the information related to image tags and other details related to version. This does not generate any application for some reason. Any suggestions? Am I missing something?
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: matrix-two-git
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  goTemplateOptions: ["missingkey=error"]
  syncPolicy:
    preserveResourcesOnDeletion: false
  generators:
    - matrix:
        generators:
          - git:
              repoURL: https://github.com/myrepo/test-app
              revision: HEAD
              files:
                - path: applications/env/**/matrix.json
              pathParamPrefix: app
          - git:
              repoURL: https://github.com/myrepo/test-app
              revision: HEAD
              files:
                - path: "version/{{.env}}.json"
              pathParamPrefix: ver
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{.cluster}}-{{.namespace}}-{{app.path.basename}}'
      labels:
        versioningfile: '{{ver.path.filename}}-'
    spec:
      destination:
        namespace: '{{.namespace}}'
        name: '{{.cluster}}'
      project: '{{.project}}'
      sources:
        - repoURL: https://github.com/test-{{.cluster}}
          targetRevision: '{{.rev}}'
          path: '{{app.path.path}}'


What files match the 1st generator and what do they contain?

Did you look at ArgoCD logs?

the issue was related to the path. I was using a submodule path, which was not working. I changed it to the actual git repo and it worked as expected.
